# Radial field dependence in optical fibers cladding

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, fiber-optics

Consider an optical fiber whose axis is the $z$-axis. Assume that the electric field $e_z$ along this direction can be written (in cylindrical coordinates) as

$$e_z(r,\phi) = A(\phi)B(r)$$

$k_c$ is the transverse (orthogonal to $z$) propagation constant. It is defined as

$$k_c = \pm \sqrt{k_2^2 - k_z^2} = \pm j \sqrt{k_z^2 - k_2^2} = \pm j \alpha$$

In the cladding $k_2 < k_z$, so $k_c$ must be pure imaginary. Function $B(r)$ is therefore determined by the modified Bessel equation:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 B(r)}{\mathrm{d}r^2} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\mathrm{d} B(r)}{\mathrm{d}r} + \left( \alpha^2 + \frac{\nu^2}{r^2} \right) B(r) = 0$$

The field is expected to attenuate as $r$ increases, so the only acceptable solutions for $B(r)$ are the modified Bessel functions of the second kind:

$$B(r) = I_{\nu}(\pm \alpha r)$$

Both $k_c = j \alpha$ and $k_c = -j \alpha$ lead to the modified Bessel equation above, so both $I_{\nu}(\alpha r)$ and $I_{\nu}(- \alpha r)$ are mathematically acceptable solutions.

**Question 1**: Are they interchangeable, or is there a difference between them?

My considerations: $I_{\nu}$ is an even or odd function if (respectively) $\nu$ is even or odd; if $\nu$ has any other value, $I_{\nu}$ is nor even, neither odd. $k_c = -j \alpha$ would lead to an $I_{\nu}$ whose sign changes when the order $\nu$ changes. Instead, $k_c = \alpha$ would lead to a uniformity in the sign of $I_{\nu}$ for any integer value of $\nu$. But I do not have a decisive argument.

**Question 2**: Are there any textbooks or websites which deal with this subject? It't very hard to find them.

---

[This document](http://wcchew.ece.illinois.edu/chew/course/tgwAll20121211.pdf), at pdf page 243, states that $k_c = j \alpha$ «is always positive imaginary», but it doesn't explain why.

Comment: Chapter 14 on Circular Fibers in *Optical Waveguide Theory* by Snyder may be a good reference for you.

Comment: @dm__ That Chapter presents the results obtained in the previous paragraphs, where the actually computation is mentioned. It seems that many steps are not included and only the results are presented. Thank you for the reference, but I am looking for a little more detailed procedure.